# How import persistence in org.jbpm.persistence.spring.jta?

Tags: spring, persistence, jbpm

I need to customize LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean for integrate jbpm with spring.But for this i need import persistence unit from org.jbpm.persistence.spring.jta.
How do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the existing kie-server-spring-boot-starter from the JBPM Team: https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-integration/tree/master/kie-spring-boot/kie-spring-boot-starters/kie-server-spring-boot-starter-jbpm